# Creating a custom popup class that extends PopupWindow

Tags: java, android, popup

I want to create an Android Application that has a Main class and a CustomPopup class.

In the Main activity, the user can enter a message in the text field and when the press the 'GENERATE POPUP' button, the message appears as a popup on the screen. The popup must be movable (drag around on screen).

[image]

[image]

What I've done so far, I really need help with the code.

**Custom popup class**

```
public class CustomPopup extends PopupWindow {

private String message;
private Double anchorX;
private Double anchorY;

PopupWindow popup;


public CustomPopup(String message) {
super();
this.message = message;

}

public void showPopup(Activity context)
{
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService
  ( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
}
```

**Main Class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

EditText messageTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageTxt);
Button generateBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.generateBtn);

String message = messageTxt.getText().toString();

 final CustomPopup popup = new CustomPopup(message);

generateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        popup.showPopup();



    }
});


}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using PopupHelper class you can use this code:

```html
public class PopUpHelper {

    static Dialog dialog;

    public static void showDialog(Activity activity, PINConfirmButtonClickListener action) {
        if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) {
            boolean isShowing = dialog.isShowing();
            return;
        }
        dialog = new Dialog(activity, R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.(your_dialog_layout);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.show();
          dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
         action.onPositiveClicked()
              "YOUR_ACTION_HERE"
            }
        });
        dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
 action.onNegative()
              "YOUR_ACTION_HERE"
            }
        });
        dialog.findViewById(R.id.close_dialog_rl).setOnClickListener(view -> action.onCloseButtonClicked(dialog));
        dialog.findViewById(R.id.resend_code_tv).setOnClickListener(view -> action.onResendCodeClicked());
    }
       public interface TwoButtonClickListener {
        void onPositiveClicked(Dialog dialog);

        void onNegativeClicked(Dialog dialog);
    }

}
```

MyDialogStyle: (Add to styles.xml)

```html
<!-- Alert Dialog Style-->
    <style name="MyAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <!-- Used for the border radius -->
        <item name="android:bottomLeftRadius">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:bottomRightRadius">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:topRightRadius">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:topLeftRadius">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:autofilledHighlight" tools:targetApi="o">@color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

and in activity calling Popup :

```html
PopUpHelper.showDialog(this, new PopUpHelper.TwoButtonClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPositiveClicked(Dialog dialog) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            
                startHomeActivity();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNegativeClicked(Dialog dialog) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }

         
        });
```

if background transparent not working set    "android:background="@android:color/transparent" to dialog layout

Example my layout but you can delete fonts and some fields:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="center"
              android:background="@android:color/transparent"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">

        <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="12dp">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/card_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="32.5dp">

                <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:paddingHorizontal="25dp"
                        android:paddingVertical="20dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:paddingTop="15dp">

                        <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/bold"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:lineSpacingExtra="4dp"
                                android:text="@string/add_to_cart"
                                android:textColor="@color/color_secondary"
                                android:textSize="18sp"/>

                        <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/medium"
                                android:lineSpacingExtra="4dp"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="@string/product_added_to_cart"
                                android:textColor="@color/color_secondary_60"
                                android:textSize="14sp"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/action_button"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="45dp"
                                android:background="@color/orange_light"
                                android:ellipsize="end"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/medium"
                                android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:letterSpacing="0.05"
                                android:singleLine="true"
                                android:text="@string/add_to_cart"
                                android:textColor="@color/white"
                                android:textSize="16sp"/>
                        <TextView
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                android:id="@+id/cancel_button"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="45dp"
                                android:ellipsize="end"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/medium"
                                android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:letterSpacing="0.05"
                                android:singleLine="true"
                                android:text="@string/cancel"
                                android:textColor="@color/color_secondary_60"
                                android:textSize="13sp"/>
                    </LinearLayout>


                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/close_dialog_rl"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/card_view"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/shape_circle_white">

                <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_close"
                        app:tint="@color/white"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

   

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/confetti_v"
                android:layout_width="65dp"
                android:layout_height="65dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_circle_orange"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_check_white"
                app:tint="@color/white"/>


    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```